How to access WSO2 API Manager installed on Minikube in AWS VM from a remote machine?
I want to install WSO2 API Manager (APIM) on Minikube within an AWS VM.
The installation is successful.
Accessing WSO2 from the AWS VM works:
curl -kv https://am.wso2.co/publisher
enter image description here
Currently, I want to access WSO2 from a remote machine. To do this, I need to route traffic on port 443 of the AWS VM to WSO2 via ingress.
How can I achieve this?
enter image description here
Thank you very much for your help!
